# How do recommendation systems work?

Tags: algorithm, recommendation-engine

I've always been curious as to how these systems work.  For example, how do netflix or Amazon determine what recommendations to make based on past purchases and/or ratings?  Are there any algorithms to read up on?

Just so there's no misperceptions here, there's no practical reason for me asking.  I'm just asking out of sheer curiosity.

(Also, if there's an existing question on this topic, point me to it.  "Recommendations system" is a difficult term to search for.)

Comment: The word "recommendation engine" is a better one to google on.

Comment: http://www.jscires.org/sites/default/files/10.5530jscires.5.1.10.pdf

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is such a commercially important application that [Netflix introduced a $1 million prize for improving their recommendations by 10%](http://www.netflixprize.com/).

After a couple of years people are getting close (I think they're up around 9% now) but it's hard for many, many reasons.  Probably the biggest factor or the biggest initial improvement in the Netflix Prize was the use of a statistical technique called [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

I highly recommend you read [If You Liked This, You’re Sure to Love That](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/11/23/magazine/23Netflix-t.html?_r=1&partner=permalink&exprod=permalink) for an in-depth discussion of the Netflix Prize in particular and recommendation systems in general.

Basically though the principle of Amazon and so on is the same: they look for patterns.  If someone bought the Star Wars Trilogy well there's a better than even chance they like Buffy the Vampire Slayer more than the average customer (purely made up example).

Answer (score 28):

At it's most basic, most recommendation systems work by saying one of two things.

**User-based recommendations:**
If User A likes Items 1,2,3,4, and 5,
And User B likes Items 1,2,3, and 4
Then User B is quite likely to also like Item 5

**Item-based recommendations:**
If Users who purchase item 1 are also disproportionately likely to purchase item 2
And User A purchased item 1
Then User A will probably be interested in item 2

**And here's a brain dump of algorithms you ought to know:**
- Set similarity (Jaccard index & Tanimoto coefficient)
- n-Dimensional Euclidean distance
- k-means algorithm
- Support Vector Machines

Answer (score 19):

The O'Reilly book ["Programming Collective Intelligence"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) has a nice chapter showing how it works.  Very readable.

The code examples are all written in Python, but that's not a big problem.

Comment: I own this book and highly recommend it.

Comment: I recommend this book to everyone :)

Answer (score 8):

[GroupLens Research](http://www.grouplens.org/) at the University of Minnesota studies recommender systems and generously shares their [research](http://www.grouplens.org/biblio) and [datasets](http://www.grouplens.org/taxonomy/term/14).

Their research expands a bit each year and now considers specifics like online communities, social collaborative filtering, and the UI challenges in presenting complex data.

Answer (score 4):

The Netflix algorithm for its recommendation system is actually a competitive endeavor in which programmers continue to compete to make gains in the accuracy of the system.

But in the most basic terms, a recommendation system would examine the choices of users who closely match another user's demographic/interest information.

So if you are a white male, 25 years old, from New York City, the recommendation system might try and bring you products purchased by other white males in the northeast United States in the age range of 21-30.

Edit: It should also be noted that the more information you have about your users, the more closely you can refine your algorithms to match what other people are doing to what may interest the user in question.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classification problem - that is, the classification of users into groups of users who are likely to be interested in certain items.

Once classified into such a group, it is easy to examine the purchases/likes of other users in that group and recommend them.

Therefore, Bayesian Classification and neural networks (multilayer perceptrons, radial basis functions, support vector machines) are worth reading up on.

Answer (score 3):

One technique is to group users into [clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_clustering) and recommend products from other users in the same cluster.

Answer (score 3):

There're mainly two types of recommender systems, which work differently:

**1. Content-based**.
These systems make recommendations based on characteristic information. This is information about the items (keywords, categories, etc.) and users (preferences, profiles, etc.).

**2. Collaborative filtering**.
These systems are based on user-item interactions. This is information such as ratings, number of purchases, likes, etc.

[This](https://tryolabs.com/blog/introduction-to-recommender-systems/) article (published by the company I work at) provides an overview of the two systems, some practical examples, and suggests when it makes sense to implement them.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the site that you're linking to? If so, you must disclose your affiliation. Here are some guidelines that you might find helpful: [How to not be a spammer](/help/promotion)

Comment: @AndrewMyers: Not sure that disclosing of affiliation is required here: The post is valuable even without the last paragraph (which contains the link). Also, the article seems isn't a subjet for affiliation: it is freely available and promotes nothing.

Comment: @AndrewMyers, thanks for your comment. I'm working at the company that published the article. However, the link to the post should only support the answer and be helpful for those who want to dive deeper into the topic of Recommender Systems. Hope they'll find it useful.

Comment: @minmidinosaur I agree, the link supports the answer and is helpful, and it's great that you're linking to it. That said, you still need to add a disclaimer of some sort (could be as simple as _"written by one of my coworkers"_). It doesn't really matter that the content is freely available; if you're linking to anything produced by your company, that needs to be disclosed. Here's another post that discusses this sort of thing: [What is the policy regarding sparse self-promotion in answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361284/5764553) I apologize for the confusion! Have a great day!

Comment: @minmidinosaur Based on your comment I edited the disclaimer into the answer. As Andrew wrote, these sorts of disclaimers are required on our site, and he gave a nice link in this direction.

Comment: Absolutely, that makes sense to me. @josliber Thanks for adding the disclaimer!

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse there is algorithms that will recommend you with prefered items. Different data mining techniques have been implemented for that. If you want more basic details on Recommender System then visit [this](http://sujitshakya.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Recommender.pdf) blog. Here every basics has been covered to know about Recommender System.